# Is this cancellation policy legal?

Tags: contract-law, european-union, consumer-protection, iceland

I reserved a motorhome in Iceland. On the invoice the cancellation policy was listed. I didn't pay the invoice and then cancelled the reservation 2 months prior to the starting date. I cancelled because I found out that it's not safe (due to weather) driving a motorhome in Iceland in November. All the campsites are closed and the laws changed in the past year; you now cannot park wherever you like. They sent me an invoice for 75% of the total, which is 1246 euros or $1400! Is this a legally binding contract?  It seems like an unfair amount to charge for a cancellation policy when cancelling two months ahead of time. What are my options?